# How do I pull Storyblok SEO data into my Nuxt app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have input my SEO info into Storyblok and can access it on the frontend of my app.

Taking advice, I intend to serve the SEO data using `useServerSeoMeta`, however I receive an error of `500 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seo')`.

Below is my code.

```js
<script setup>
const { slug } = useRoute().params
const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
const resolveRelations = ['ProductGroup.products']
 
const story = await useAsyncStoryblok(
  slug && slug.length > 0 ? slug.join('/') : 'home',
  { version: runtimeConfig.STORYBLOK_CONTENT_VERSION ,
  resolve_relations: resolveRelations,
 },
)

useServerSeoMeta({
  title: () => story.content.seo.title,
})

</script>
 
<template>
  <StoryblokComponent v-if="story" :blok="story.content"  class="mx-3"/>
</template>
```

I assume it's an async issue, so I tried a variation of:

```js
<script setup>
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useAsyncData(
  'mountains',
  () => $fetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains')
)
</script>
```

Taken from https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data - to no avail.

Can anyone help me assign the SEO data correctly please?